What is the "diameter" of the Mandelbrot set?
I don't know if there is a more official term for what I'm about to describe so let me know if there is so I can change it.
Pick a line l such that it passes through at least 1 point on the Mandelbrot set. Color all of the points on the line that are part of the Mandelbrot set red and color the rest black. Consider all of the red line segments and sum all of their lengths. Now pick a new line l and do the same process I just described, and repeat this over and over up to some number k. Then, add up all of these sums and divide them by k; in other words, you calculate the average of the lines l. What does this average approach as k grows without bound?
I know that depending on which method you choose to find a random line, it can yield different answers. So here's the way I'm doing it:
Pick an angle in degrees to be the slope (The line y = 0's angle would be 0 degrees, the line y = x's slope would be 45 degrees, the line x = 0's slope would be 90 degrees, and the line y = -x's slope would be 135 degrees). The way we will choose this angle is by picking a random number from 0 to 179 (inclusive) to represent the digits on the left side of the decimal place. Next you would choose a random number from 0 to 9 (inclusive) for the tenths place. Then you'd choose a random number from 0 to 9 for the hundredths place, and so on.
To choose the y intercept, you'd do a very similar process. You'd choose a number between 0 and 9 (inclusive) for the tenths place, choose a number between 0 and 9 (inclusive) for the ones place, then a number between 0 and 9 for the hundredths place, then a number between 0 and 9 for the hundreds place, and so on. Of course, we'll be excluding any and all lines that don't intersect with the Mandelbrot set.

It isn't necessary to come up with an involved algorithm for generating a random value for the desired distribution; you only need to specify the distribution. For the angle, it suffices to say it is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0, 180)$ degrees. ¶ The $y$-intercept is a whole nuther matter, though. There is no uniform distribution on the reals, and no obvious alternative choice either, since the line could have a $y$-intercept anywhere in the reals and still intersect the Mandelbrot set.
